# A class in a header does not include all variables and functions?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sdl-2

This .h file, that is included in the game file, doesn't recognize variables and a function "as in scope":

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "SDL2/SDL.h"

class Igra
    {
    private:
        SDL_Renderer *obl;
        SDL_Window *okno;
        bool traja;
        Uint32 Takt_zac;
    public:
        Igra();
        ~Igra();
        void zanka();
        void posodobi();
        void vnos();
        void oblikuj();
    };
#endif // GAME_H
```

The game.cpp that I made:

```
#include "game.h"

#define fps 60

Igra::Igra()
{
    SDL_Init(0);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(360,240,0,&win,&ren);
    SDL_SetWindowTitle(win,"Planet Saver");
    traja=true;
    void loop();
}

Igra::~Igra()
{
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void Igra::zanka()
{
    while(Igra::traja)
    {
        Takt_zac=SDL_GetTicks();
        void kon30(Uint32 Takt_zac);
        oblikuj();
        vnos();
        posodobi();

    }
}
void kon30(Uint32 Takt_zac)
{
    if((1000/fps)>SDL_GetTicks()-Takt_zac)
        SDL_Delay(1000/fps-(SDL_GetTicks()-Takt_zac));
}
void Igra::oblikuj()
{

}
void Igra::vnos()
{

}
void Igra::posodobi()
{

}
```

Errors that the compiler makes:

```
    ||=== Build: Debug in g0.1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
G:\SDL+igra\g0.1\game.cpp||In constructor 'Igra::Igra()':|
G:\SDL+igra\g0.1\game.cpp|10|error: 'traja' was not declared in this scope|
G:\SDL+igra\g0.1\game.cpp||In member function 'void Igra::zanka()':|
G:\SDL+igra\g0.1\game.cpp|23|error: 'traja' is not a member of 'Igra'|
G:\SDL+igra\g0.1\game.cpp|25|error: 'Takt_zac' was not declared in this scope|
G:\SDL+igra\g0.1\game.cpp|27|error: 'oblikuj' was not declared in this scope|
G:\SDL+igra\g0.1\game.cpp|38|error: no 'void Igra::oblikuj()' member function declared in class 'Igra'|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Using `using namespace std;` is usually not recommended, but it is a mortal sin in a header file. Might even cause your problem, since you do so before including third party header. Even more importantly: Judging from the error message, your problem is not really connected to SDL, so please prepare a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can't repro the missing `traja`s on my Debian Stable system with GCC 6.3.  Instead it can't find `win` and `res` in `Igra()` and `~Igra()`.

Comment: You have more than one file named "game.h" on your system, and you are not including the one you think you are.

Comment: Can't see your problem. For me all compiles ( if I remove SDL stuff which I have not on my system and change data types to common ones. What has your question todo with "codeblocks"?

Comment: idk:1. I removed using namespace std-didn't work

Comment: 2.the only similar file near the project is SDL_gamecontroller.h, third might I ask if it is a problem that I have it on aUSB stick?

Comment: A simple check to see if your header is being included is to add an obvious compilation error (I typically add a line that is just `ugh;` at the top, before any include guards) then compile to see if you get the error.  If you don't then the wrong header file is being included or you have recursive includes.

Comment: when adding ugh; it removes all function and variable errors, but whines about ren and win- repro'd genpfault's problem

Comment: I give up- gonna do it in one file

Comment: dd it in one file, works near perfect. Just asking how to close this thing?